# Ejs output parent.child is not iterable

Tags: javascript, loops, mongoose, iteration, ejs

I'm trying to iterate over 'redirect' subdocuments from my qr model but am receiving the type error `qr.redirect is not iterable`. The iteration is setup on the client side in my ejs template:

**EJS render**

```
<% for (let q of qr.redirect) {%>
    <h1><%= q.name %> </h1>
<% } %>
```

**Controller function**

```
module.exports.showActivations = async (req, res) => {
    const qr = await Qr.find({ user: user._id });
    res.render('users/activations', { qr });
};
```

**qr.js model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const qrSchema = new Schema({
    redirect: [{
        name: String,
        url: String,
        qrcode: String,
    }],
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    event: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Event'
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Qr', qrSchema);
```

What's interesting is if I run `console.log(qr)` in the controller function, the redirect subdocuments are logged as `[ [Object] ]` but if I run `console.log(qr[1])` (for example) the entire document and subdocuments key:value pairs are logged.

Not sure if the above idiosyncrasy has anything to do with my client side error but would love some help on how to fix my client side for loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure `qr.redirect` has a length greater than zero in the `if` condition. Then apply `forEach` loop on the list.

```
<% if(qr.redirect.length){ %>
    <% qr.redirect.forEach(user=> %>
       <%= user.name %>
     <% })  %>
<% }%>
```